# Why can't string literals stored into txt file using fwrite function

Tags: c, string, struct, fwrite, string-literals

```
typedef struct student
{
    int rno;
    char *name;
} student;

void create(){
    student *s;
    FILE *fp;
    int n, j, i;
    char nam[50];
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    s = (student*)calloc(n, sizeof(student));
    fp = fopen("ask.txt", "w");
    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        printf("Enter rollno: ");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].rno);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", nam);
        s[i].name = nam;
        fwrite(&s[i], sizeof(student), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The question requires the name to be a string literal.
Is it possible to store string literals into a txt file using fwrite?
The s[i].name contains the input, but it couldn't be stored in the txt file

Comment: This also fails without storing anything into your file. If you print your array in a second loop (not in your first loop) you will notice that all entries will hold the same string because they all point to the same buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Strings *can* be stored into files using fwrite.

The problem with the code you exposed, concerning this particular question, is that the struct student does not contain a string: it contains a pointer to a string.

It should work better with a struct like this one:

```
typedef struct student
{
    int rno;
    char name[50];
} student;
```

Comment: ... and use `scanf("%49s", nam);` to prevent buffer overflow